# YouTube Player API: getDuration(), getCurrentTime(), getVideoData() not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

For my application, I am trying to use the YouTube Iframe player API to play videos, and allow the user to change videos without reloading the page.

I accomplish this by using the `player.loadVideoById(video_id)` method. After loading the video via YouTube video id, I also want to capture all relevant information about the video. However, I notice that none of the get functions work right away, including `getDuration()`, `getCurrentTime()` and `getVideoData()`.

I have found a scrappy solution of using a `setTimout` to get the information about 1-2 seconds after using `player.loadVideoById(video_id)`, however, I do not think this is the proper solution.

It seems to me that `loadVideoById(video_id)` is asynchronously fetching the data from YouTube. Is there a callback function available to use? I could not find one in the docs. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: hey, did my suggestion work for you? if it did, can you select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few **[Events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events)** available that you can utilise I think.

Here is an example of tracking `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING` state, falling within the `onStateChange` event, which is basically saying that the video is currently being played.

```
player.addEventListener(YT.PlayerState.PLAYING, onVideoPlaying, false);

function onVideoPlaying() {
  console.log('currentTime:', player.getCurrentTime(), 'duration:', player.getDuration());
}
```

Hope this helps.