# player.getDuration() and player.getCurrentTime() is not function error?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have read similar questions posted but none did help my case.

Here is my YouTube `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="myframe" style="border: solid 4px #37474F; ">
</iframe>
```

I added the `src` attribute dynamically.

Here is my player:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('myframe', {

    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

I am trying to do `player.getCurrentTime();` and `player.getDuration();` but both keep giving the "function not defined" error.

Comment: Maybe these links help you [YouTube Player API: getDuration(), getCurrentTime(), getVideoData() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001561/youtube-player-api-getduration-getcurrenttime-getvideodata-not-working) // [How to get duration of a loaded/cued video without playing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086260/youtube-player-api-how-to-get-duration-of-a-loaded-cued-video-without-playing-i)

Answer (score 3):

The YouTube player API sets `player.getCurrentTime` not in the constructor but later (possibly when the video is loaded). Likely, this is a bug.

To see that this is true add `console.log(player.getCurrentTime)` before each call. You will see that this is `undefined` initially and later changes to a function.

Work around this by testing whether `player.getCurrentTime` exists. If not, assume a return value of `0.0`. Example:

```
var videoPos = !player.getCurrentTime ? 0.0 : player.getCurrentTime();
```

The same problem seems to happen with `getDuration`.

Answer (score 0):

As usr said, it's likely a bug. And here's another solution:

```
var yourVariable = player.getCurrentTime() || 0;
```